# Digital clock source

Tags: digital-logic, clock

I'm currently on an adventure into digital electronics. I've built a bunch of logic, but to test it I need a clock source.

Is there a way I can “easily” construct a square-wave oscilator adjustable from 1 Hz to, say, 10 Hz?

Currently I have a big stack of 74HC00 chips, some LEDs and some resistors.

One of my old electronics books had an LED blinking circuit which (from memory) used a NAND gate as in inverter, and put a capacitor across it to slow it down. Those were 74LS00s though. So, TTL. I doubt my CMOS chips would enjoy the very slow rise time of a large capacitor.

I suppose the “standard” solution is to just build a one-transistor oscilator. But from what I've seen, transistor circuits are always an *insanely* complex network of dozens resistors and capacitors. I'd like something simpler if possible. (Besides, they're usually sinewave oscilators, not square wave.)

I guess maybe I could buy a Schmitt-trigger inverter and use that with a capacitor... It seems a shame to have to buy an entire batch of parts just for the clock. But I think I'm probably going to have to do that anyway. (At the very least, it seems an oscilator requires *some* kind of energy-storage device, and I currently have none.)

(The other alternative is a crystal — but I don't understand how those work, I suspect you still need lots of additional components, and I highly doubt anybody makes a 10 Hz crystal.)

Comment: You should get a bag of capacitors for decoupling anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My go to device for an *adhoc* clock is the hex Schmidt trigger device xx14, whether LS14, HC14, or AC14.

Ok, you've bought six in a pack, but the pack costs pennies, and you're not going to need a few extra inverters somewhere? ...as LED drivers? ... as input buffers?

The CMOS devices can go sub-Hz with big resistors, and with no explicit capacitor (only strays) and a <1k feedback resistor, the AC device can crank out many 10s of MHz. How's that for flexibility?

However, 50 EUR/USD/GBP will get you a 60MHz function generator on xBay, with a nasty user interface, but it's functional. I've got one, it works, 'nuff said.

Comment: Given that Schmidt trigger buffers might also be useful for debouncing... this is probably what I'm going to go with.

Answer (score 1):

For DIY projects, I would try to get a cheap function generator. If you insist on a onboard clock source for that frequency range, I believe the standard way is to use a [555 Timer IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC). And yes, you need some energy storing device; capacitors are great for just that. I assume you will need capacitors for decoupling anyways – so get a set of different values.

Comment: I thought the 555 was decades obsolete by now? (Although I have no idea what the replacement is supposed to be...)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid If it does the trick in an elegant manor, it is a good solution regardless of age.

Comment: It's brilliant at what it does, but like most special purpose ICs the replacement is "a microcontroller"

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple schematic [found here](https://www.electroschematics.com/simple-square-wave-generator-with-7400/), using only 74LS00 gates. The source says it works from 20 Hz to 1 MHz, but I'd try with 74HC00 and larger capacitors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbx3rC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It introduces the hysteresis through the capacitor. To understand the circuit, start with a HIGH at the input of NAND1 and a voltage of 0V over the capacitor. Then the capacitor will be charged through R2 ... The rest is left as an exercise for you. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion for the clock at the very low frequency you want, especially for interactive experimentation and debugging, is to do it manually. Driving a pushbutton by hand at 1Hz will get tedious quickly, so arrange something like a microswitch against a toothed wheel, or a series of contacts like a pulse-dialling phone.

This gies you a system with variable clock rate that can easily be stopped at any time to debug it. Ideal in combination with a PDP11/70 style front panel.

(The crank was a feature on some minicomputers, but I can't now find a reference for this)

You should debounce it in order to ensure correct operation - so another capacitor across the output, a pullup resistor, and feed it through a schmitt trigger to clean it up.

Comment: For debounce you could also use a NC/CO switch that feeds an RS flip-flop built from 2 NANDs.